# Use users preinstalled .net library version - C#

Tags: c#, .net, libraries

I have created app in Visual C# which uses DotNet library. On my machine the app runs okay (obviously) and also on my second laptop which I use at work. Problem is - at work we have group policies enabled so that we cannot install anything. Colleagues have different laptops and different DotNet libraries. Some have 4.6, some 4.5, some 2.6. Is there a way to design app that it will fetch or set, which library it will use ? So will test it, if the app can run on any version and then users will dont have a problem to run it on whatever version they have preinstalled. Is it possible ?

Comment: You should find what is the lowest framework installed and create your app using that version

Comment: Compile your app for the lowest .Net Framework version you can.  Require your users to use that version or higher.

Comment: ok, thanks I will try.

Comment: just don't try to set it to 2.6 :] https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb822049